# Segmentation Fault when iterating std::vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I have a method that will be called many times in succession to perform iterative printing of a std::vector object that contains objects of std::vectors.

```
class Message
{
public:
    struct Child
    {
        Child:a(0.0F),b(0.0F)
         {}
         float a;
         float b;
    };
    struct Parent
    {
          Parent:x(0U),y(0U)
          {}
          unsigned char x;
          unsigned char y;
          std::vector<Child> childList;
    };

    Message();
    ~Message();
    printingMethod();
    addParent();

private:
    unsigned int s;
    unsigned int t;
    std::vector<Message::Parent> parentList;
}

Message::addParent(Message::Parent newParent)
{
    parentList.push_back(newParent);
}

Message::printingMethod()
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;

    for(unsigned int i = 0U; i < parentList.size(); i++)
    {
        const Parent myParent = parentList[i];

        std::cout << myParent.x << std::endl;
        std::cout << myParent.y << std::endl;

        for(unsigned int j = 0U; j < myParent.childList.size(); j++)
        {
            const Child mychild = myParent.childList[j];

            std::cout << mychild.a << std::endl;
            std::cout << mychild.b << std::endl;
        }
    }
}


Main()
{
    Message myMessage;
    //some code to initialise myMessage's vector by calling addParent
    //....
    //...

    int idx = 0;
    while (idx < 10000000)
    {
        myMessage.printingMethod();
        idx++;
    }

}
```

If the while loop only loops for say 100 times, there will be no problem. However, if I increase the while loop to say 10000000 times, there will be a chance of segmentation fault at this section:

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0U; i < parentList.size(); i++)
    {
        const Parent myParent = parentList[i];//<-segmentation fault

        std::cout << myParent.x << std::endl;
        std::cout << myParent.y << std::endl;

        for(unsigned int j = 0U; j < myParent.childList.size(); j++)
        {
            const Child mychild = myParent.childList[j];//<-segmentation fault

            std::cout << mychild.a << std::endl;
            std::cout << mychild.b << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

But if I simply change it to be a reference object, there is no segmentation fault.

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0U; i < parentList.size(); i++)
    {
        const Parent & myParent = parentList[i];//<-no segmentation fault

        std::cout << myParent.x << std::endl;
        std::cout << myParent.y << std::endl;

        for(unsigned int j = 0U; j < myParent.childList.size(); j++)
        {
            const Child & mychild = myParent.childList[j];//<- no segmentation fault

            std::cout << mychild.a << std::endl;
            std::cout << mychild.b << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why do I get segmentation fault for the copied object, but not for the referenced object?

Or is the "fix" just a fluke, and I will get segmentation fault eventually?

TIA.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. It's often the case that a question author incorrectly determines which part of the code is problematic and doesn't post code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: pasting down the sizes of your `parentList` and corresponding `childList` might help.

Comment: `const Parent myParent = parentList[i]` and `const Child mychild = myParent.childList[j]` make a copy every time they are called. Most likely you are allocating too much memory. `const Parent & myParent = parentList[i]` and `const Child & mychild = myParent.childList[j]` are const references referring to an already existing element you created the first time hence it's working fine.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @L.F. Yes i did. That's how i found out which line of code caused the seg fault.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang While debugging the code, the debugger found the 2 lines of code that will cause the seg fault. I believe that I have done range check for the vectors correctly, and I do not have any other array or pointers. The only change I made was to add in a reference inside the iteration.

Comment: @v78 Not sure if it helps, but the size of parentList is 7 and childList is 4.

Comment: Did you run your program under Valgrind (or a similar checker)?  That's usually a good way to identify memory access problems.

Comment: This code doesn't compile: it has multiple syntax errors and is missing function definitions.

Comment: Just because a segfault occurs on one line doesn't mean the error is there. It's very possible that you corrupted some memory earlier causing good code to segfault. We need a [mcve] in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To aid you in finding why it seg faults, as pointed out in the comments, you want to sprinkle your code with some couts to see the size of the vector and the indices you use (j).

Also using `myParent.childList.at(j)` will throw exactly when you go out of bounds.

In your case, the use of references simply turns on some optimisations, which could explain why it doesn't seg fault, but you shouldn't rely on that.